# Getting HBitmap from IGraphBuilder

Tags: video, encoding, directshow, hbitmap

I'm trying to encode a video from an IGraphBuilder, for this I would require a HBitmap is it possible for me to do this?

P.S. I know that IGraphBuilder already has a RenderFile function, however this is too slow for my use and I would also prefer to render in H264

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`IGraphBuilder` controls the pipeline, it does not have, own and even have a faintest notion of bitmaps or their handles.

The typical approach is to insert a `Sample Grabber` filter into the pipeline and grab video frames off there (there is a plenty of sample code around there on doing this). Still you have to provide more detail about your particular task to get reasonable advice.

Comment: Thanks for the info! Is there any overhead when using a sample grabber (for real time use). Basically what I'm aiming to do is add two videos (one from a webcam) as a filter to the igraphbuilder then render it out as a video file.

Comment: Sample Grabber itself has a minimal overhead, however as soon as you start your `filtering` you will add your own overhead, plus if you are going to require specific video format such as RGB, it might also add implicit conversion with its own additional overhead.

Comment: That's good! I'll have a look at some samples and have a go at doing this! Thanks for the help!